# How to deploy service in Cloud Foundry?

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am a newbie in CloudFoundry and I will appreciate your help.

So, I need to create CF ServiceBroker for our product and I try to figure out how to do it properly.

I've found in the documentation types of deployments:

> https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/overview.html
>
> The following are examples of valid deployment models.
>
> 1) Entire service packaged and deployed by BOSH alongside Cloud Foundry
>
> 2) Broker packaged and deployed by BOSH alongside Cloud Foundry, rest of
>   the service deployed and maintained by other means.
>
> 3) Broker (and optionally service) pushed as an application to Cloud Foundry user space
>
> 4) Entire service, including broker, deployed and maintained
>   outside of Cloud Foundry by other means

I've seen so far examples of deployment type 3 and 4 - it is obvious - all I need just to implement ServiceBroker API, deploy it and create service broker with the command 'cf create-service-broker'. And with these deployment type, I need to maintain my service back end. For example, if my service provides MongoDB as a service, I need to have the server (for example in Amazon) with installed MongoDB database. And ServiceBroker will delegate all apps there.

But I can't find any examples of 1 and 2 deployment type. As I understood so far the first deployment type allows to deploy ServiceBroker and Service backend on Cloud Foundry. So, with this type, I need not to have the separate server with installed MongoDB, but I can deploy, somehow,  Mongo database to the CloudFoundry.

So, my questions are:

1) is my understanding correct?

2) is there are any examples how to deploy service broker and service backend on CLoudFounry?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What type of service? Which Bluemix? What kind of account do you have? What privileges? A good start: https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/Bluemix-ServiceBroker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) No, it allows you to deploy your own releases/deployment alongside with CloudFoundry (or on a separate IaaS) using bosh.

The proper question to ask is "How to create a bosh release for my application and service broker with bosh v2 manifest deployment".

2) The best way is to look on existing projects within https://github.com/cloudfoundry and https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community, like https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-mysql-deployment and https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-mysql-release

More on https://bosh.io/docs#basic-deploy and https://bosh.io/docs/manifest-v2.html

Prepare for a high learning curve.

Comment: Could you describe what does it mean "deploy own releases/deployment alongside with CloudFoundry"? Does it mean that I can deploy CF by myself for example on AWS with BOSH and also I can deploy my Service Backend on AWS too with BOSH?

Comment: That's correct.

This way your service backend can be managed using bosh in the same way as CF and reuse some of the existing releases, like https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/mongodb-bosh-release